# Not able to resolve OR method while configuring multiple controllers in swagger spring boot

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-boot, swagger

I am new to swagger and need to configure multiple controllers in spring boot swagger UI. But getting some issues as I am not able to resolve OR class/method in swagger when using with regex. Please let me know how can I resolve or keyword here. The basic need for me is I need to configure more than one controller paths in swagger UI.

[image: I am getting below error in eclipse.]

Comment: You can just use `.paths(PathSelectors.regex("^/(test-data|bkc-user-details).*$"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You are actually trying to use ant matchers in regex construct moreover you don't really need to use `or` method here.

You can use:

```sh
.paths(PathSelectors.regex("^/(test-data|bkc-user-details).*$"));
```

To match these 2 URI paths. If you want you can add more alternations in future this way.